# Android Tablet, menu overflow position

Tags: android, android-actionbar, tablet

I'm reading in many sites that i can't move the menu overflow. The thing is, i have another app on my tablet that the overflow is on the bottom bar, on the right side from the back, home and applist button. Unfortunately, i don't have the code of this app =(

What i have to do to put the menu overflow with the other buttons?

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENUID_TEST, 0, R.string.test);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENUID_TEST2, 1, R.string.test2);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);     
}
```

Comment: isn't it at the bottom because it's kinda 'legacy'? http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: "The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower, set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher." I'm using android:minSdkVersion="10" and android:targetSdkVersion="11", the legacy way isn't to work?

Comment: "the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app **on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher**". What version of Android are you on?

Answer (score 0):

As Stephan said in his comment, this 'menu' icon is shown for older apps written for Android 2.x that do not have an ActionBar but a normal options menu. Also, this icon is only shown if the device does not have a physical menu button.

onCreateOptionsMenu must return true in order for the menu to be shown.

Try this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENUID_TEST, 0, R.string.test);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENUID_TEST2, 1, R.string.test2);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, if i can't move the overflow on android 4.0.3, i have a serious problem, because by default, my app have no title bar, and the menu overflow only appears if i have it..

Comment: You can implement the menu like older apps do by implementing `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: I'm already doing it. Ops, let me show you some code, wait 10 seconds. Code added to original post.

Comment: See my modified answer -- onCreateOptionsMenu must return true in order to show the menu as described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

Comment: Nothing, if i remove the title, the menu overflow disappear and not appear in the bottom bar.

Comment: How do you remove the title?

Comment: I'm using a style for my application theme: <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid I have no further ideas :-(